# Convert map of probabilities to value

Tags: kotlin

So I have a map of items to probability.

```
----------------------------------------
| enum_example      | int_ probability |
|______________________________________|
| ENUM.ITEM_ONE     | 89               |
| ENUM.ITEM_TWO     | 10               |
| ENUM.ITEM_THREE   | 1                | 
----------------------------------------
```

And I want to take this data, and use it to get each item that percentage of time. So, 89% of the time I get ITEM1, 10% of the time I get ITEM2, and 1% of the time I get ITEM3. I want to always get at least one of the items.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can do this by combining them into a full range, and picking a value from that range at random. So you roll a random number between 1 and 100, and then

- if it's between *1* and *89*, get `ITEM_ONE`
- if it's between *90* and *99*, get `ITEM_TWO`
- if it's *100*, get `ITEM_THREE`

That's just for illustration - it's actually better to shift these numbers so they're zero-based, i.e. `ITEM_ONE` is between *0* and *88*, because that's how Kotlin works in general and a lot of functions work on that basis.

```
val value = Random.nextInt(100) // picks an int between 0 and 99

return if (value < 89) ITEM_ONE // value between 0 and 88
else if (value < 89 + 10) ITEM_TWO // i.e. between 89 and 98 (since it can't be less than 89)
else if (value < 89 + 10 + 1) ITEM_THREE // between 99 and... 99
else throw("won't happen because value is 99 at most")
```

That `throw` is only there because you need a final `else`. You could just replace the last `else if` branch with `else ITEM_THREE` because what else is it going to be if you reach that point? But that structure there is what you can build algorithmically with the `scan` and `first` functions, so I wanted to give an idea of how this actually works (example code [here](https://pl.kotl.in/_LfvQ8FpA)):

```
// just to make the code read better than using a Pair
data class ItemProb(val item: Item, val upperBound: Int)

// get each item's (exclusive, i.e. has to be less-than) upper bound on the distribution
// by adding its probability to the previous item's upper bound
val distribution = Item.values()
    .scan(0) { total, item -> total + item.probability } // [0, 89, 99, 100]
    .drop(1) // don't want that initial 0, result is [89, 99, 100]

// pair up each Item with the bound we calculated for it
val lookup = Item.values()
    .zip(distribution)
    .map { (item, upperBound) -> ItemProb(item, upperBound) } // create an ItemProb from each pair
```

Then you can grab items with

```
// roll a value from 0 until (not including) the upper bound of the whole distribution
val value = Random.nextInt(lookup.last().upperBound)
// grab the first item where the rolled value is within that bounded range
val item = lookup.first { value < it.upperBound }.item
```

You don't have to make that data class, you can skip the `map` call after the `zip`, and the `zip` will give you a list of `Pair`s of *Items* and *upper bounds*. But you'd have to use `first` and `second` to access them and it's not very clear to the reader what those mean!

---

You could also create *inclusive* `IntRange`s instead of upper bounds, [if you like that better](https://pl.kotl.in/7qllPJY3-):

```
data class ItemProb(val item: Item, val range: IntRange)

val distribution = Item.values()
    .scan(0) { total, item -> total + item.probability }
    .zipWithNext() // instead of dropping the 0, we get [(0, 89), (89, 99), (99, 100)]
    .map { it.first until it.second } // turn them into ranges, excluding the top value
    // [(0..88), (89..98), (99..99)]

// lookup is the same, just combining the Items with their derived ranges
val lookup = Item.values()
    .zip(distribution)
    .map { (item, range) -> ItemProb(item, range) }
println(lookup)

// upper bound for the nextInt call needs to be the upper bound of the highest range
// -plus 1- since those ranges are -inclusive- - need to call it with 100, not 99
val value = Random.nextInt(lookup.last().range.endInclusive + 1)
// now you can just use the -in- operator, find the range that -value- falls into
val item = lookup.first { value in it.range }.item
```

Or if you want, you could just create `distribution` without `lookup`, use `distribution.indexOfFirst { // compare value to upperBound or range }` to get an index, and grab the corresponding item with `Item.values()[index]`. (I reckon it's a good idea to store `Item.values()` in a variable so you aren't creating a new array every time you call it)